# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi... ERROR

Tags: java, android

AS me muestra un error en la siguiente linea, el problema es que causa que mi app se detenga, y cuando voy a la actividad en java aparece subrayada en rojo, no se bien porque razón

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

activity2 java, este es el código completo de la actividad

```
    package com.websmithing.gpstracker;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.TimeZone;

    //import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

    public class LocationService extends Service implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {

        private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

        // use the websmithing defaultUploadWebsite for testing and then check your
        // location with your browser here: https://www.websmithing.com/gpstracker/displaymap.php
        private String defaultUploadWebsite;

        private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            defaultUploadWebsite = getString(R.string.default_upload_website);
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
            // no need to start processing a new location.
            if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
                currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
                startTracking();
            }

            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        private void startTracking() {
            Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

                googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();

                if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    googleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
            }
        }

        protected void sendLocationDataToWebsite(Location location) {
            // formatted for mysql datetime format
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            Date date = new Date(location.getTime());

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            float totalDistanceInMeters = sharedPreferences.getFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);

            boolean firstTimeGettingPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);

            if (firstTimeGettingPosition) {
                editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", false);
            } else {
                Location previousLocation = new Location("");
                previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
                previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));

                float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
                totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
                editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
            }

            editor.putFloat("previousLatitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
            editor.putFloat("previousLongitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
            editor.apply();

            final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
            requestParams.put("latitude", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            requestParams.put("longitude", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

            Double speedInMilesPerHour = location.getSpeed()* 2.2369;
            requestParams.put("speed",  Integer.toString(speedInMilesPerHour.intValue()));

            try {
                requestParams.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

            requestParams.put("locationmethod", location.getProvider());

            if (totalDistanceInMeters > 0) {
                requestParams.put("distance", String.format("%.1f", totalDistanceInMeters / 1609)); // in miles,
            } else {
                requestParams.put("distance", "0.0"); // in miles
            }

            requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
            requestParams.put("phonenumber", sharedPreferences.getString("appID", "")); // uuid
            requestParams.put("sessionid", sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", "")); // uuid

            Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28;
            requestParams.put("accuracy",  Integer.toString(accuracyInFeet.intValue()));

            Double altitudeInFeet = location.getAltitude() * 3.28;
            requestParams.put("extrainfo",  Integer.toString(altitudeInFeet.intValue()));

            requestParams.put("eventtype", "android");

            Float direction = location.getBearing();
            requestParams.put("direction",  Integer.toString(direction.intValue()));

            final String uploadWebsite = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", defaultUploadWebsite);

            LoopjHttpClient.get(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - success", uploadWebsite, requestParams, responseBody, headers, statusCode, null);
                    stopSelf();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                    LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - failure", uploadWebsite, requestParams, errorResponse, headers, statusCode, e);
                    stopSelf();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

                // we have our desired accuracy of 500 meters so lets quit this service,
                // onDestroy will be called and stop our location uodates
                if (location.getAccuracy() < 500.0f) {
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    sendLocationDataToWebsite(location);
                }
            }
        }

        private void stopLocationUpdates() {
            if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
         * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
         * request the current location or start periodic updates
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // milliseconds
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

// this line of error            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

            stopLocationUpdates();
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de android 6.0 (Marshmallow) Android cambió la manera en la que pide los permisos. Ya no los pide al instalar la app, sino que los pide en tiempo de ejecución (a los que considera riesgosos) o los concede automáticamente (a los que no considera riesgosos, para ver una lista de los grupos de permisos y a cuales considera riesgosos podes entrar aca: [Lista de permisos normal-dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936914/list-of-android-permissions-normal-permissions-and-dangerous-permissions-in-api/36937109)).
El warning que te indica Android Studio es justamente que te falta pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecución, o que manejes una SecurityException (con try... catch).

Para pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecución podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  // Check Permissions Now
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        REQUEST_LOCATION);
} else {
  // permission has been granted, continue as usual
  Location myLocation =
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

Necesitas chequear también el permiso `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` (`INTERNET`  y `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` no necesita ser chequeado porque no se considera "riesgoso" y Android te lo concede automáticamente).
Y en el `onRequestPermissionsResult` chequeas si el usuario te concedió los permisos o no:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        if(grantResults.length == 1
           && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We can now safely use the API we requested access to
            Location myLocation =
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        } else {
            // Permission was denied or request was cancelled
        }
    }
}
```

También recorda agregar la dependencia en gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Hola, soy nuevo en esto, donde debo ubicar el fragmento uno y dos, gracias

Comment: Deberías pedirlos en el activity o fragment que utilize el LocationService (en tu caso es GpsTrackerActivity si no me equivoco) y deberías pedir los permisos antes de usar el LocationService, así te aseguras de tener los permisos necesarios y que no te crashee la app... En caso de no tenerlos podrías pedirlos de nuevo o informar al usuario que los necesitas para que la app funcione correctamente, o no hacer nada... Eso depende mucho de como quieras manejar ese escenario.

Comment: Por las dudas te hago otra aclaración... el fragmento de código 1 (donde chequeas si te dieron los permisos) iría adentro de algún método en el activity que utiliza el LocationService... y el fragmento de código 2 es un método del Activity o Fragment que se sobreescribe para saber si el usuario te concedió los permisos en caso de que se los hayas pedido